# How do I access my private browsing history?

Tags: mac, dns, logs, web-browsing, opera

I'm trying to recover some pages that I had open when my macbook (OSX 10.8.5) crashed.

Unfortunately I was using Opera (V30) in private browsing mode. 
I've tried looking at my DNS cache - but not exactly sure how to read it. (I can't see the URLs in the text)

I've also looked at my router logs but can only find info like this:

```
May 9 00:39:27> PPPD Successfully Launched
May 9 00:39:32> pppd 2.4.3 started by root, uid 0
```

Just to let you know - I'm not trying to snoop on anyone, really just want to recover the pages I had open!

Comment: I think that's the whole idea of private browsing ;-) You could see if your router logs show recent connections

Comment: Yes, stupidly using private browsing on a laptop prone to crashing! I can’t seem to find any useful info on my router logs (see below)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from a Wikipedia:

[Privacy mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode)

> **Privacy mode** or "**private browsing**" or "**incognito mode**" is a privacy feature in some web browsers to disable browsing history and
>   the web cache. This allows a person to browse the Web without storing
>   local data that could be retrieved at a later date. Privacy mode will
>   also disable the storage of data in cookies and Flash cookies. This
>   privacy protection is only on the local computing device as it is
>   still possible to identify frequented websites by associating the IP
>   address at the web server.

You may try to find logs from any routing, filtering or tracking hardware or software inside your network, or from your Internet provider.

Comment: Thanks! 
I have contacted my ISP provider, but they told me that they don’t retain the browsing history. Also I tried logging in to my router (D-Link DSL-502T ADSL router) but the log doesn’t give me any info that shows web or IP addresses.
I also use airport extreme. Perhaps there is a way to access the info through this?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to retain such logs from Airport Extreme. 
Please be consider selecting the answer if at least helped you with information.